# How to run multiple consoles from one class?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have three classes which all make different works but I need to run them together. When I run all of them in one class I just get one console and cant change this console. What I want is to run them in one class and see each console . How can I do that ?

To be more clear ,

```
when I run first class, I get --> console 1
when I run secondclass, I get --> console 2
when I run third class, I get --> console 3
```

but instead of doing it seperatly, when I do it;

```
Run 1,2,3 ----> I get console 1
```

The thing I want is

```
Run 1,2,3 ----> I get console 1, 2 and 3
```

Thank you all

**EDIT 1 :** Sorry for not-enough info I use Eclipse to run my code, and I am talking about Eclipse console.

Comment: Are you using an IDE like Eclipse or NetBeans?

Comment: How are you opening up a console? Or are you using the one given to you?

Comment: A little more info please. How are you running them ? Console command, through an IDE, something else ?

Comment: @MikeG yes I am using Eclipse and also sometimes I use SpringSource Tool

Comment: @ Peter Lawrey I just run the code I have written so I can get the Eclipse Console

Comment: @Simeon Sorry for not-enough info, I use Eclipse and I run my code

Comment: Not possible AFAIK. Your output will be going to the same console if it's being invoked from the same `main` method. Why do you want to do this anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A certain way to do it would be to open 3 separate terminals and do `java Class<n>` (without .class extension) in each terminal.
2. I don't think you can do it in Eclipse with a single workspace (it could be possible though ...), one way to do it is to create separate projects for each class and open each project in a separate workspace simultaneously, but this is too much work IMO. 1. is probably the easiest/fastest way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to invoke `java` command separately for each class in different console. With one `java` invocation, i think, there will be only one console associated.

Answer (score 0):

Obscure question. But it seems that you need separate console outputs for your classes. I don't think it is possible. That is operating system restriction. If operating system supported that you could somehow create additional consoles.

As a solution you can give your classes PrintStream object which they will use to output data.

Answer (score 0):

You could run a server-like application which would accept messages and then display them in the console. The class would start each of your other main methods in new Threads, and then wait indefinitely for messages, ending when the other three threads close.

Answer (score 0):

INMO, if your underlying OS is Windows then you need to handle console and use JNA or JNI that allows you to call win32APIs from java, but if your underlying OS is Unix-like then you need to find a way to communicate with syscall APIs in java. by calling native APIs you can call native console and if you know how to create a native console then you can create multiple instances of native console.