# Display multiple console in java from same program

Tags: java, jcreator

I'm trying to make application to display multiple consoles windows in java from same program:

- First console will print "Hello from Console 1"
- Second console will print "Hello from Console 2"

I was reading about threading, but I found only that I can made multiple threads, and start them, but display one Console window.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run multiple consoles from one class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501258/how-to-run-multiple-consoles-from-one-class)

Comment: thanks , but this post applied for Eclipse , I'm using JCreator Si mo